Numpy reshape() to display 2D array in 3D programmatically
Example Data
I have an array of weather data by lat/lon in the following shape: (1038240,4) (See photo for sample example data)
I want to reshape this to the shape (4,721,1440) which would be four weather variables (& lat/lon) over a 721 by 1440 image of the globe.
I have tried:
newarr = t_new.reshape(4,721,1440) 

which puts this in the correct shape, but doesn't match this to the first two lat/lon coordinates to the preferred format below:
For the (6,4) example data in the photo above, this operation would look like a (2,3,2) array below:
Example Desired Output
newarr = t_new.reshape(4,721,1440) 


First reshape to (721,1440,4).  Or transpose to (4,1038240) and then try reshape.  You don't want to mix in the 4 with the otgers.  Sometimes it's easier to experiments with something smaller, where you can actually visualize what's happening.

Do not include data as images but rather include it as text

Split your array into 4 separate ones, since lat.lon are numbers, and temp/pressure are letters.  They don't belong in one array.

Thanks for the responses. When I transpose t_new first, and then reshape it - my output of the new sliced as follows: newarr[:,1,:]
Looks like this:
0 0.25 0.75 1.25
89.75 -90 -89.5 -89
102497.2043 100278.161 100292.9734 100285.1228
-9.701471509 0.308991492 -2.319560451 -2.460140388
So both lat and lon are varying here. Ideally my output array is (4,721,1440) with 4 as the variables, 721 as the latitude and 1440 as the longitude. So a slice like this should have the latitude as constant

Further investigation reveals that numpy.reshape() operates in row-major (C-style) order by default, which means it fills the new array along the last axis first (i.e., from left to right, top to bottom)
So if I reshape this first then transpose:
reshaped = t_new.reshape((1440, 721, 6))  # Reshape to (1440, 721, 4)
correct_order = reshaped.transpose((2, 1, 0))  # Swap axes to get (4, 721, 1440)

It seems to produce the desired output. I test this by looking at the slices to see that longitude/latitude are constant along each slice:
correct_order[:,:,1]
correct_order[:,1,:]

Thanks to comments from hpaulj for hint to transpose this.
